# Setup WordPress multi-site installation to handle both subdomain.example.com and www.subdomain.example.com

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect, subdomain, multi-subdomains

I have installed a multi-site installation of WordPress onto my domain. I then added the necessary code to the `wp-config.php` file and `.htaccess` as instructed by WordPress.

I also installed a plugin called Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin which allowed me to place a 301 redirect onto the main domain as I only want to use the sub domain and not the main domain. Then I also added the following line of code to the `wp-config.php` file to redirect the main domain `define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'URL Redirect Address' );`

The site works fine with a redirect on the main domain and my subdomain runs fine when you type in `subdomain.example.com` or `http://subdomain.example.com`.

However when I enter `www.subdomain.example.com` or `http://www.subdomain.example.com` the following error message is returned:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) Server at www.subdomain.domain.com Port 80

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's normal because `www` is a subdomain of `subdomain.eaxmple.com`, you can add a new redirect to your subdomain if want to.

Comment: The address for your subdomain is http://subdomain.example.com, there is no www in front of a subdomain, you'll need to add a redirect as Zistolen suggests, to redirect www.subdomain.example.com to subdomain.example.com.

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I add the re-direct?

Comment: How did you create the subdomain, are you using cPanel?

Comment: I created the subdomain using wordpress multi site installation. I didn't make any changes myself on the server, therefore there is only 1 httaccess file for both the subdomain and the domain.

Comment: @ECarterYoung `www` is just a sub-domain name. There can be a `www` in a sub-domain, such as `www.sub2.sub1.example.com`.